# Can you have an enum with a string property?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to develop a light client/server program(s). An 'admin' program shall be able to send common commands to several local client machines with the client program installed.

I have an Enum to control the common commands like so:

```
public enum Command
{
    Reboot,
    StartService,
    ShowMsg
}
```

With that I can send commands from the admin program like this:

```
Command.Reboot
```

And on the client program I can have a switch statement to do what is asked by that command.

However, for some parts of the enum I need a string property to send with this.

Like from the admin program, I would like to send something like this:

```
Command.ShowMsg("Hi, this is a string message")
```

How do I accomplish this? I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Does it HAVE to be an enum? I'd do this with a class, with an enum property from your current enum and a string, which is null for Reboot and you can assign it when it's not.

Comment: Does not have to be enum. Could you please show me how to with a class?

Comment: You can merely add a custom attribute to the enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a class, which contains the enum, like so:

```
enum CommandType
{
    Reboot,
    StartService,
    ShowMsg
}
[DataContract]
class Command
{
    [DataMember]
    public CommandType CmdType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public CommandType(CommandType cmd, string value = null)
    {
        CmdType = cmd;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

And then just use it like this when needed:

```
new Command(CommandType.ShowMsg, "Hi, this is a string message.");
```

Comment: In order to use this object as parameter in your contract, you need to specify serialisation of the fields/properties. Decorate your class with the [DataContract] attribute and your two properties with the [DataMember] attribute. While you're on it, you may also capitalize the property names. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by changing the contract of the service. So in a contract you can have

```
interface IFooService
{
    void Execute(Command cmd);
    void ExecuteWithParam(Command cmd, string param1);
}
```

This will however create problems with people trying to understand how to use such API. There is also a maintenance problem if you try to refactor the service later. So a better option would be to use one dedicated method per one value of enum, instead of using generic `Execute` method (or whatever you call it) and pass an enum, like so:

```
interface IFooService
{
    void Reboot();
    void StartService(string[] args);
    void ShowMsg(string msg);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you then want to add another command? You have to make a new interface. Not good.

Comment: No, you add a method to the current interface

Comment: That breaks compatibility with all the classes that implement it.

Comment: It is a service, you are supposed to design a contract first. If you decide to change it, this will also mean you have to update the client side proxies anyways. What if some of your methods require an `int` parameters, some require a DTO, some require 5 parameters and some none? How will you implement that?

Comment: Use an abstract class with default implementations of `throw new NotImplementedException()`?

Comment: Method overloads in WCF contracts are not permitted (due to SOAP limitations) and your first code example is therefore not working. Please give the second Execute-Method a different name.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a class.

```
public class ServiceObject{

public String command {get;set;}
public String message {get;set;}

  public ServiceObject(String command,String message){
   this.command = command;
   if(message!=null)
     this.message = message;

  }

}
```

You would create this obeject by doing

```
new ServiceObject("ShowMessage","This is a Service Object");
```

or

```
new ServiceObject("Restart",null);
```

Now on your server side just accept a Service Object

You can check its properties by doing `ServiceObject.command` and `ServiceObject.message`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Though I don't like that one have to write our the command.
You can easily misspell a command and it will still compile, but will error when used.

Eg.      New ServiceObject("Restarr", null); <-- misspelled, will compile
Eg.      Command.Restart; <-- can not be misspelled and will not compile

Comment: True, however the difference is with my solution you only have to modify the code in one spot, which is optimal. You only have to add the new functionality into your server solution then you can use it. There are many tools out there to solve the same problem. The question is which one operates better for you.